# Cobol program to print its executable name

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I am trying to find a clause by which i can get the name of executable
,is it possible to print COBOL executable name when executable is run

Comment: That'll be highly dependent on your flavor of COBOL and mainframe OS. Typically, things like the program name aren't available inside the program, but only in whatever job control language is used to actually run the program. Some flavors of COBOL have a feature to get the command line, and depending on your system the executable name may be the first component of that command line.

Comment: Are you talking about in the COBOL program using a DISPLAY or other command to write out the program name and other information ?

Answer (score 3):

With [Enterprise COBOL on z/OS](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/ibm-cobol), you might try looking at the prolog, either the entry name, found in `PPA1` or the compilation unit name, found in `PPA4` - more info about this on [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ceev100/initpib.htm).

Comment: And http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21392963 which looks like dereference a pointer at address 548, add 172 to squirrel into the ASCB from the PSA to get the job initiator (ASCBJSNI).  Adding 176 from the PSA block seems to get the pointer to the job name, ASCBJSNM.